# Помогите с регулярным выражением, выбрать id обьекта с ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая ссылка - `https://vk.com/dengi_gov?w=wall-65888168_1444`

Как вытащить с нее этот кусок `-65888168`

Comment: А регулярки обязательно? Можно и без них: ищите позицию `wall`, обрезаете строку, чтобы она начиналась с символа, следующего за этим `wall`, затем в полученной строке ищите первый `_` и обрезаете строку до этого символа. Если регулярки обязательно, то можно этот алгоритм перенести и на них: `wall([^_]*)_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много способов. Вот один из них:

```
$url = "https://vk.com/dengi_gov?w=wall-65888168_1444";
$parts = parse_url($url); // Получаем доступ к частям URL
$qry = $parts['query'];   // Достаём строку запроса
parse_str($qry, $output); // Делим строку запроса на пары ключ-значение
// Дальше можно и та
echo preg_replace('/^[^-]*(-[^_]+).*$/s', '\1', $output['w']); // => -65888168
// Можно и так
preg_match('/-\d+/', $output['w'], $m);
echo $m[0];  // => -65888168
```

[Демо-код](http://ideone.com/PvXWRp)

Это регулярное выражение - `^[^-]*(-[^_]+).*$` - находит строку, в которой в начале может быть любое число символов, отличных от `-` (`^[^-]*`), потом наша искомая подстрока (минус и 1 или более символов, отличных от `_` (`-[^_]+`), а потом любое количество любых символов до конца строки (`.*$`). Искомая подстрока захватывается в буфер 1, из которого и восстанавливается при замене с помощью шаблона `\1`.

Но с `/-\d+/` гораздо проще :)

P.S. `preg_match('/-\d+/', $qry, $m);` работает даже без `parse_str`:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$qry = $parts['query'];
preg_match('/-\d+/', $qry, $m);
echo $m[0];
```

[Демо-код на IDEONE.com](http://ideone.com/28Pdwv)

Comment: Спасибо Вам, вы меня очень выручили.

Comment: Лучше так `/(\d+)_\d+$/` https://regex101.com/r/BbRyFD/1

Comment: @Alex78191 Конечно,  и так тоже можно.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте документацию:

http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

```
preg_match("w=wall-(.*?)_.*?$", ...)
```

Comment: Указываете документацию, а сами пишите код с ошибками - синтаксически неверный.

Comment: Ошибки? Хорошо, добавлю многоточие, Ромео :-)

Comment: @Чад, имелось ввиду, что пример, как минимум, должен содержать delimiter, т.е. должен был быть таким: `preg_match("/w=wall-(.*?)_.*?$/", ...)`, иначе php вернет false: *Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash*. И еще - знак `-` должен быть включен в группу

Comment: @BOPOH: Я то и другое имел в виду :) Чад, ТС бывают разные - чёрные, белые,... Скопирует, запустит и пребежит вновь сюда со словами: "у меня ошибки". В [данном случае](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461278/10551), необходимо всё разжевать, кроме того, уважать себя, как разработчика - быть аккуратным и немного перфекционистом.

Comment: В принципе я согласен, хотя я за то чтобы программисты думали, информации которую я предоставил в принципе достаточно чтобы самостоятельно дойти до решения. А это более полезно чем просто сделать копи паст и потом ныть что всё не правильно :-)